# Is there a way to obfuscate material-ui classnames?

Tags: material-ui

Websites like airbnb.com do not use deterministic css classnames. I'm aware that the class names generated by @material-ui/core/styles are non-deterministic but I'd also like to make the classnames generated by @material-ui/core non-deterministic. I'm using gatsby and have tried many different ways to generate non-deterministic @material-ui/core classnames with no success.

Comment: hi, interesting perhaps this might be of interest https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21281

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this one before and it doesn't work